# Rive can't load asset on android

Tags: flutter, dart

I was testing using rive animation in Chrome and it works perfectly, but as the appliacation is for mobile, I connected to android and... failed.

I get an error:

[image]

Since web works and mobile version does not I expect it to be a kind of a bug? Is there someone who solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you were using `RiveAnimation.file`. you should use the `RiveAnimation.asset` method.

also, you have to let the app knows where is your rive file:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/path/to/file.riv
```